# Trim href in an HTML anchor node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hey I need to trim content within in each `<a>` tag to a character limit 20 within a description node using XML 1.0. Here is the XML

```
  <description> 
       This is text <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718323/edit">http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718323/edit</a>. 
       Also here is more text than we have another 
       <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718323/edit">http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718323/edit</a>.
  </description>
```

What I need it to turn into is this:

```
  <description> 
       This is text <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718323/edit">http://stacko</a>. 
       Also here is more text than we have another 
       <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718323/edit">http://stacko</a>.
  </description>
```

I can do most the logic, but I'm having trouble doing a "for-each" that searches through the description node and transforms "each" < a >.

Does this make sense? Any help appreciated.

** EDIT 2/7/13 ***

Based on the answers provided here is where I am at now.

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//description"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a">
    <a href="{@href}">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(),1,20)"/>
    </a>
   </xsl:template>
```

The problem is "apply-templates" won't work because I have multiple templates in my XSL. I need to call a template specifically, so I assumed "call-template" would be the route to go. The only problem with "call-template" is I don't know how to specify an specific XML node to reference. Here is how I've hacked it so far (deosn't work):

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="trim_text"/>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="trim_text" match="//description">
     <a href="{@href}">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(),1,20)"/>
     </a>
    </xsl:template>
```

The initial 'call-template' needs to be in a `<xsl:template match="/">` because this is going in a much larger function. So I need 3 things:

1) the HREF to stay consistent with what is in the XML

2) The text between the `<a>` tag to be trimmed to 20px

3) I need to call this template from inside a much larger xsl template which does a lot of transformation on the XML. This will be of around 7 template calls.

Comment: concatenate? What does the output needs to look like?

Comment: My apologies. Basically I need to limit the characters in the < a > tag to 20px. So for example... "http ://www.longlink/morelink/page/anotherpage"  would have to be shortened to "http ://www.longlink/mor"

Comment: I think you mean "trim" instead of concatenate

Comment: Yes your right, my apologies. Also I had to re-revise the comment because I need to text inside the <a> tag to be trimmed, not the href. Sorry for not being clear up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is "apply-templates" won't work because I have multiple templates in my XSL. I need to call a template specifically, so I assumed "call-template" would be the route to go. The only problem with "call-template" is I don't know how to specify an specific XML node to reference.

Template *modes* may be what you are looking for

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- do some other stuff ... -->

    <!-- handle the description -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//description" mode="description" />

    <!-- more other stuff here -->
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- description-specific templates -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="description">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="description" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a" mode="description">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="description" />
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 20)" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you specify a mode with `apply-templates`, only templates that are marked with the same mode are considered when finding the template to apply to each node (plus the default implicit template that matches all element nodes and recursively applies templates to children *using the same mode*, but that doesn't apply here as we have an identity template).  This example template for `a` elements doesn't allow for links that contain other tags, for example

```
<a href="#">This is a <b>very</b> long piece of text used as an example</a>
```

would become

```
<a href="#">This is a very long </a>
```

If you want to preserve such markup it gets much more complicated.  You can't do it with the obvious approach of

```
<xsl:template match="a//text()" mode="description">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 20)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

because this would treat each text node in isolation, and produce

```
<a href="#">This is a <b>very</b> long piece of text </a>
```

(as "This is a " and "very" are already shorter than 20 characters, and " long piece of text " is the truncation to 20 characters of " long piece of text used as...")

Comment: This works amazing! Thank you so much. I really appreciate the descriptions as well, makes everything quite clear. One question I had was what does "@* | node()" mean? That's the only thing I'm confused about.

Comment: So I just realized the XML is wrapped in CDATA, so my output is `&lt;a href="http://">` instead of `<a href="http://">` Do you know of any way around this?

Comment: @user2001026 The template matching `@*|node()` is the _identity template_ of XSLT - it copies its input to output verbatim.  `@*` matches any attribute node and `node()` matches any element, text node, comment or processing instruction.  The template creates a copy of the matched node in the output and then recursively applies templates to any children.  Any XSLT task that involves making small tweaks to the input XML can usually be solved by using an identity template and then selectively overriding it (as with my template matching `a` elements) for anything you want to handle differently.

Comment: @user2001026 if the content of `<description>` is wrapped in a CDATA then it is treated by the parser as plain text, not XML, and you won't be able to match the `a` "element" with XSLT (element in quotes because it's not an element, it's just the text angle bracket, a, space, href...).  You might be able to get some way towards what you want using string manipulation functions but XSLT 1.0 is rather limited in the string handling it can do.  Depending on your processor you may be easier writing an extension function in a more appropriate lanuage (Java, VB, whatever your processor supports).

Comment: Thank you so much Ian! I really appreciate all the help you've been. This all makes great sense now. Your hard work is very much appreciated. I'll keep poking and see what I can find.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation avoids the use of `xsl:attribute` , is better formatted and more readable**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a[@href]">
  <a href="{substring(@href,1,20)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='href')]|node()"/>
  </a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document:**

```
<root>
    <description>
            This is text 
        <a href="http://www.longlink/morelink/page/anotherpage">Link Here</a>.
            Also here is more text than we have another
        <a href="link-style:null">Link Here</a>.
    </description>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <description>
            This is text 
        <a href="http://www.longlink/">Link Here</a>.
            Also here is more text than we have another
        <a href="link-style:null">Link Here</a>.
    </description>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **[Identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** -- to copy as is every node for which this template is selected for execution.
2. Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Template).

Comment: This looks and works great for the href, but the problem is I need the text inside the <a> tag to shorten, not the href. Can this code be tweaked to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, use: `<xsl:template match="a/text()"> <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(),1,20)"/></xsl:template>`

Comment: This is great and works awesome thanks! The only problem I am having right now is "apply-templates" applies all templates in the XSL document correct? Well I have a bunch of templates in the XSL (around 7). I only want to apply the one template to trim the above links. I am going to store this in a variable and output it later on. Can you use "call-tempalte" with this code? It kept breaking for me.

Comment: Just add a "name" attribute to the template -- then you can call it with `xsl:call-template`

Comment: Here is where I am at. I know select in call-template is invalid, but how do I reference that node?

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:call-template select="//description" name="trim_text"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="trim_text" match="a">
  <a href="{@href}">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(),1,15)"/>
  </a>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: call-template only takes name, you should not specify select. Also note that the context within which you are calling the named template is the root node, so you will have in your result tree a single a href wrapped around the fifteen characters of all of the text nodes in your source XML.

Comment: @user2001026, Please, *edit* the question and clearly explain your new requirements -- best with example. It isn't clear what you want exactly.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks in advance for all your help! You are really helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question as revised in the OP's comment that he needs to limit the characters to 20 characters.

Try the substring function to return just the first 20 characters:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,20)"/>
```

Here is a more complete answer:

**This XSLT 1.0 transform:**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>  
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="a/@href">
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,20)"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to this XML document:**

```
    <root>
        <description> 
            This is text <a href="http://www.longlink/morelink/page/anotherpage">Link Here</a>. 
            Also here is more text than we have another 
            <a href="link-style:null">Link Here</a>.
        </description>
    </root>
```

**Results in the desired result (note the shortening of the first href attribute):**

```
    <root>
        <description> 
            This is text <a href="http://www.longlink/">Link Here</a>. 
            Also here is more text than we have another 
            <a href="link-style:null">Link Here</a>.
        </description>
    </root>
```

**Explanation:**

- The identity transform (the first template) will copy all of the nodes and attributes to the result tree,
- The second template will copy only the first 20 characters of an href
- Also note the lack of for-each, but rather the use of a template rule and apply-templates. Where you can, you should use templates.